# Implement server side with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new in `node.js`, and I try to create a HTTP server, with some commands like: upload, download, user, etc.

I implement the server side by the [next guide](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#building-the-application-stack). It use the `HTTP` & `URL` modules.

But now I discover the express module, which I can use the get and posts methods. Can I say that the [express module](http://www.mfranc.com/node-js/node-js-simple-web-server-with-express/) replace the first implementation? What the advantages and disadvantages of the `express` module compared with the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often occurs, this comes down to a question of self-developed, tailored code vs generic, but well-supported code.

Unless you have very specific needs and performance requirements outside the usual, then Express will almost certainly provide you with everything you need for a server implementation, without you having to worry about the code itself.

Bear in mind also that something like a server is inherently at-risk security wise, so there's another pro for using a well-maintained library there (not that they're inherently secure or stable *per se*, but they're often moreso than something you've written yourself).

Answer (score 0):

[express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) module gives us some extra feature to implement and create a mvc. Like I use it and implement to do some project. For example [docanddo](https://docanddo.com). express remove the worries of url operations and fileupload adn session handling and lots of feature. we can use several middleware  to build the best.